# Flying balloon animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a simple animation of a balloon moving from bottom to top. First loop works fine and then it starts some random motion. i.e. I want balloons to come one after the other from bottom to top without any randomness. And repeat.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="message">1. Bob</div>
    <div class="message">2. Alice</div>
    <div class="message">3. Eve</div>
</div>


jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function(vertSpeed, horiSpeed, index) {

    this.css('float', 'left');

    vertSpeed = vertSpeed || 1;
    horiSpeed = 1/horiSpeed || 1;

    var windowH = this.parent().height(),
        thisH = this.height(),
        parentW = (this.parent().width() - this.width()) / 2,
        rand = Math.random() * (index * 1000),
        current = this;

    this.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
    this.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    setInterval(function() {
        current.css({
            marginTop: function(n, v) {
                return parseFloat(v) - vertSpeed;
            },
            marginLeft: function(n, v) {
                //return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 5000) + 1000) + 1) * parentW;
                return (Math.pow(new Date().getTime() / ( 5000) + 1000) + 1);
            }
        });
    }, 15);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
            current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
        }
    }, 250);
};
var message = 1;
$('.message').each(function(message) {  
    $(this).verticalMarquee(0.5, 0.5, message);
    message++
});

parent {

    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

.message,.message-1 {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    z-index: -9999;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znrhkf3c/12/

Any help here is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution could be to use only [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) for this animation. You can change the duration and delay as you want.

```css
#parent {
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.message {
 position:absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: -120px;
 height: 120px;
 width: 120px;
 background-color: orange;
 color: white;
 line-height: 115px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 60px;
 animation: move 6s infinite linear;
}
.message:nth-child(2){
 left:120px;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}
.message:nth-child(3){
 left:240px;
 animation-delay: 4s;
}
@keyframes move {
 0% {
  bottom: -120px;
 }
 100% {
  bottom: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
   <div class="message">Bob</div>
   <div class="message">Alice</div>
   <div class="message">Eve</div>
</div>
```